# pandas dataframe plot error, possibly stale indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following error when plotting a DataFrame. I'll try to replicate it minimally ... I'm guessing the index is somehow messed up from a index.drop call. At this point it seems like a bug.

UPDATE: This code reproduces the error on my setup (python 3.3.2)

```
import pandas
from pylab import *

print('pandas version', pandas.__version__)
df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(6,2))
df.index = pandas.Index(['2013-05-03 00:00:00', '2013-05-01 00:00:00', '2013-05-01 00:00:00', '2013-05-02 00:00:00', '2013-05-06 00:00:00', '2013-05-07 00:00:00'], dtype=object)
# this one passes!?
# df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(5,2))
# df.index = pandas.Index(['2013-05-01 00:00:00', '2013-05-01 00:00:00', '2013-05-02 00:00:00', '2013-05-06 00:00:00', '2013-05-07 00:00:00'], dtype=object)
print(df.shape)
print(df)
df.index = [pandas.datetools.parse(x) for x in df.index]
print(df.shape)
print(df)
try:
    df.plot()
    print('first df.plot() passed')
except Exception as e:
    print('Caught Exception on df.plot()', e)
df = df.sort_index()
print(df.shape)
print(df)
df.plot()
print('df.plot() works after df.sort_index()')
```

Results:

```
$ python3 p.py 
pandas version 0.12.0
(6, 2)
                            0         1
2013-05-03 00:00:00  0.049095  0.199115
2013-05-01 00:00:00 -0.637439  0.201922
2013-05-01 00:00:00 -1.441205 -0.006792
2013-05-02 00:00:00  1.673248  1.558569
2013-05-06 00:00:00 -0.168974  0.457340
2013-05-07 00:00:00 -0.165104 -1.642641
(6, 2)
                   0         1
2013-05-03  0.049095  0.199115
2013-05-01 -0.637439  0.201922
2013-05-01 -1.441205 -0.006792
2013-05-02  1.673248  1.558569
2013-05-06 -0.168974  0.457340
2013-05-07 -0.165104 -1.642641
Caught Exception on df.plot() Shape of passed values is (2, 8), indices imply (2, 6)
(6, 2)
                   0         1
2013-05-01 -0.637439  0.201922
2013-05-01 -1.441205 -0.006792
2013-05-02  1.673248  1.558569
2013-05-03  0.049095  0.199115
2013-05-06 -0.168974  0.457340
2013-05-07 -0.165104 -1.642641
df.plot() works after df.sort_index()
```

Comment: pls supply more information, without seeing your data series, nor what operations you are performing, one can only guess

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it in any simple way. I'm not sure how to present the example otherwise ... I was more fishing to see if anybody had encountered this error before. I did not see anything from a quick search of the issues tracker on github. Probably a strange corner case.

Comment: why don't you post a notebook or a full code listing. This is a standard error messag showing that you your data and index do not line up (e.g. they are different shapes)

Comment: @Jeff, I think I finally tracked it down. Unless I'm missing something obvious, it seems like triplicate DateTimeIndex entries trigger some corner case in .plot.

Comment: FWIW, I get no exceptions on Python 2.73, pandas v0.12.0-429-g6f9e3bd. 'first df.plot() passed'

Comment: @DanAllan Thanks. Just checked and I also get a pass on the newer version. Good news.

Comment: gr8, fyi, you should use ``to_datetime`` instead of manually parsing the datetime